# Mock method that returns Task<dynamic>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, task, moq

I have unit test for a method that returns dynamic and when I try to setup and returns a dynamic value it gets an error on running the test saying

> The best overloaded method match for 'Moq.etc' has some invalid arguments

```
_managerMock.Setup(x => x.someMethod(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(resource));
```

Comment: What is resource? Also show the definition of what is being mocked and how it is being used in the test

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

### With var

If your `resource` variable is not declared as `dynamic` then you don't need anything special. All you need is the good old `ReturnsAsync`. (Please prefer `ReturnsAsync` over `Returns` with `Task.FromResult`)

```cs
var resource = new {Id = 1};
_managerMock.Setup(mgr => mgr.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(resource);
```

In this sample I've created an anonymous type but you can use whatever you want.

### With dynamic

If you declare your `resource` as dynamic then you need to use another overload of the `ReturnsAsync`. Instead of specifying the return `value` you need to specify the `valueFunction`.

```cs
dynamic resource = new {Id = 1};
_managerMock.Setup(mgr => mgr.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(() => resource);
```

In this sample I've created an anonymous lambda but you can use whatever you want.